# How do I customize the alert sound for an iPhone timer?

Tags: iphone, ios

When the countdown timer ends I would like to set the IPhone to play a custom music file. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to save the file you'd like to play as a ringtone, then the iPhone can play it once the timer hits zero. The big limitation here is that it'd need to be ~35 seconds in length, but depending on your specific need, that might be enough.

There are a few apps on the App Store that will allow you to create ringtones from music files, or you could [do it yourself in Garageband](http://support.apple.com/kb/VI205). The linked instructions are for Garageband '11, but searching "garageband ringtone" at Apple support will yield links for various other versions of Garageband - the process is pretty much the same.

Comment: you mean it needs to be 35 seconds because ringtones are limited at 35 secs?

Comment: yeah, you'd need to cut down the track in order to be able to send it to iTunes as a ringtone.